# How to save a keras model when both precision and recall are better?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Using `python 3.7` and `tensorflow 2.1.0` I would like to know how to save the best model when both precision and recall are better.

The following code gives elements to save the best model when only the precision is better.

```py
# some dependencies
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Precision, Recall

# some coding instructions to define ImageDataGenerator flows.

metrics = {"precision":Precision(name="precision"), "recall":Recall(name="recall")}
checkpoints = {
    "precision" : ModelCheckpoint(
        "./models/best.h5",
        mode="max",
        monitor="val_precision",
        save_freq="epoch",
        save_weights_only=False,
        save_best_only=True,
        verbose=1
    )
}
callbacks = list(checkpoints.values())

model = Sequential()
# neural network architecture ...
model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=[metric for metric in metrics.values()]
)

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    validation_data = val_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size,
                    validation_steps = val_generator.n//val_generator.batch_size,
                    class_weight={0:0.75, 1:1.5},
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                    epochs=300)
```

I don't think that adding a callback for the recall will enable me to save the best model for both metrics... In my opinion, if recall is better than the recalls computed in last epochs, the model will be saved even if the precision is getting worse... Same for the precision. I think that this kind of code will only give us a kind of "OR" logic instead of "AND" logic.

May be I am wrong... Can someone help me ? Any help would be really appreciated. Explanations are very welcome !

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a solution, hope it will help some guys.

```py
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, path, metrics):
        self.model = model
        self.path = path
        self.metrics = metrics
        self.history = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        if self.history:
            last_logs = self.history[-1]
            last_metrics_values = {metric : last_logs[metric] for metric in self.metrics}
            current_metrics_values = {metric : logs[metric] for metric in self.metrics}
            checking = [last_metrics_values[metric] < current_metrics_values[metric] for metric in self.metrics]
            decision = reduce(operator.and_, checking)
            if decision:
                print("\nModel performs better at current epoch for all monitored metrics : ", self.metrics)
                print("\nSaving current model in ", self.path)
                self.model.save(self.path)
        else:
            print("\nSaving model at first epoch for initialization purpose")
            self.model.save(self.path)
        self.history.append(logs)
```

You can change the code to have more complex logic to decide when saving the model and what is for you the best model. The decision is computed using `checking` and `decision`. You must have the following dependencies :

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator

import tensorflow as tf
```